# Issues setting focus on div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tsx, recharts

I'm trying to set focus on a div element so my tool tip modal will be scrollable without having to mouse over that element the problem is my recharts tooltip has too much data and is spilling out on the next graph and the next graph tooltip is spilling of page.
my thinking was set a max height on tooltip and allow it be scrollable.

heres what i have tried.

```
     <div
      ref={ this.setFocus }
      onFocus={ this.handleFocus }
      className="custom-tooltip"
      styleName="custom-tooltip"
     >
```

and for my setFocus function

```
setFocus = (div) => {
 if(div !== null && this.props.active) {
  const myDiv = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(div) as HTMLDivElement;

  return myDiv.focus();
 }
}
```

my onFocus function is never getting triggered.

Comment: *I'm trying to set focus on a div element so my tool tip modal will be scrollable...* A `div` element may not receive the focus. Generally, only items that can be tabbed to can receive the focus.

Comment: you can give divs a "tabindex". cant you?

Comment: No, you can't give them focus.

Comment: To make a div focusable, assign `tabindex="0"` to it.

Comment: tocqueville you duh bomb

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus non form elements without any works around with this elements. Use form elements for focus(`input`, `textarea`), or you can attach third party `contenteditable` react components to your project like: [react-contenteditable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable), [react-content-editable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-content-editable) or vrite your self `contenteditable` component to your prject.